# ECDSA.recover versus ECDSA.tryRecover

Tags: signature

Is one of these better than the other? How do you decide which one to use?

I see that they take different forms of the signature and hashed message but I'm wondering more about whether one is better than the other

Comment: Can you please provide more context, what library are you using to call these functions? with more info we can go through the docs and discover the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can refer https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/api/utils#ECDSA for more details. Anyway the simple fact is this,

1. `ECDSA.recover` - This doesn't return an error if something wrong with the signature. It will only return the `address` of the signer. In this case you can see returning `address(0)` when an error occurs.
2. `ECDSA.tryRecover` - This returns the `address`, `error`, and *details related to the error*. There will be no such cases like returning `address(0)`

Using `tryRecover` will help you falling into unwanted troubles. But if you want to proceed anyway with an error you can use `recover` directly or `tryRecover` with an error handling. Anyway, it will be more helpful and informative if you provide more details about the Contract you are developing and libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

as for openzeppelin lib as I assume it is about it, `recover` just uses `tryRecover` and reverts in case of error, they both do same and have same arguments

tryRecover doesn't revert but returns error dat:

```
    function recover(bytes32 hash, bytes32 r, bytes32 vs) internal pure returns (address) {
        (address recovered, RecoverError error, bytes32 errorArg) = tryRecover(hash, r, vs);
        _throwError(error, errorArg);
        return recovered;
    }
```

Also both functions are overloaded, both have different arguments but same way. You may have seen different ones